# how to perform Secured FTP in iis 6.0

Tags: ftp

i found in some website that using port 443 performs secured ftp, but using 443 i'm not able to perform ftp. what is the configurational changes i've to make  in c# code and in ithe iis 6.0 FTP Site.

I am using C# .

Answer (score 0):

To perform secure FTP in C#, you must find a library to do so, such as described here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FTP_Secure.aspx

IIS 6 doesn't support FTPS, but I think IIS 7 might. You should ask on serverfault if you need to know that.